# issues with having setState in useEffect causing delayed state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am working on this slider effect using React Hooks and Redux. My codes are the following:

```
const Barchart = ({chartData}) => {
    let newArray = []
    let len = chartData.length

    const [XArray,setXArray]=useState([chartData])
    const [Yarray,setYArray]=useState(chartData[len-1].anArray) //so the initial state here should be an empty array
    // const d3Container = useRef(null);   


    useEffect(()=>{
        let len = chartData.length
        console.log(chartData.length)
        newArray = chartData[len-1].anArray
        setYArray(newArray)

        if(newArray.length!==0){
        const height = 70 //height of the actual chart, different than the svg element
        const width = 26.5*newArray.length //width of the actual chart, different than the svg element

        const svg = d3.select('.svg-canvas')
        svg.selectAll("*").remove()

        var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,7]).range([0,width])
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,d3.max(Yarray)]).range([height,0])

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(8)
        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5)

        //locate the chart in the middle of the svg frame: 800/2 - width/2
        var chartGroup = svg.append('g').attr('transform','translate('+(400 - width/2)+',300)')
        
        
        chartGroup.selectAll("rect").data(Yarray).enter().append("rect")
                .attr("height",(d,i)=>d*3)
                .attr("width","15")
                .attr("fill","blue")
                .attr('x',(d,i)=>26.5*i)
                .attr('y',(d,i)=>height-d*3)
                
        chartGroup.selectAll('text').data(Yarray).enter().append("text")
                .attr('font-size',15)
                .attr('x',(d,i)=>26.5*i)
                .attr('y',(d,i)=>height-5-d*3+2)
                .text((d,i)=>d)
        
        chartGroup.append('g').attr('class','axis y')
                // .attr('transform','translate(500,76)')
                .call(yAxis)

        chartGroup.append('g').attr('class','axis x')
                .attr('transform','translate(0,'+height+')')
                .call(xAxis)
        }
    },[chartData])

    const newArrayFunc = (a) =>{
        setYArray(a)
    }

    return(
        <div id='chart-container'>
            <h3>Bar Chart</h3>
            <svg className="svg-canvas" width="800px" height="400px"></svg>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    chartData:state.chartChange
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Barchart)
```

So as you see, even though I have setYArray in the useEffect, its asynchronous features prevent Yarray from being immediately updated. **Whenever I have a new array coming from `chartData`, the d3 bar chart uses the previous array.**

The objective I am trying to achieve here is whenever the array from chartData gets updated, the updated array will then be used in the d3 bar chart right after.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Continue using the same `newArray` value you updated state with

```
const Barchart = ({ chartData }) => {
  let newArray = [];
  let len = chartData.length;

  const [XArray, setXArray] = useState([chartData]);
  const [Yarray, setYArray] = useState(chartData[len - 1].anArray); //so the initial state here should be an empty array
  // const d3Container = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let len = chartData.length;
    console.log(chartData.length);
    newArray = chartData[len - 1].anArray;
    setYArray(newArray);

    if (newArray.length) { // <-- use in-scope newArray value
      const height = 70; //height of the actual chart, different than the svg element
      const width = 26.5 * newArray.length; //width of the actual chart, different than the svg element

      const svg = d3.select(".svg-canvas");
      svg.selectAll("*").remove();

      var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 7]).range([0, width]);
      var y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(newArray)]) // <-- use in-scope newArray value
        .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(8);
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

      //locate the chart in the middle of the svg frame: 800/2 - width/2
      var chartGroup = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (400 - width / 2) + ",300)");

      chartGroup
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(newArray) // <-- use in-scope newArray value
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d * 3)
        .attr("width", "15")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => 26.5 * i)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => height - d * 3);

      chartGroup
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(newArray) // <-- use in-scope newArray value
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => 26.5 * i)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => height - 5 - d * 3 + 2)
        .text((d, i) => d);

      chartGroup
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis y")
        // .attr('transform','translate(500,76)')
        .call(yAxis);

      chartGroup
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    }
  }, [chartData]);

  const newArrayFunc = (a) => {
    setYArray(a);
  };

  return (
    <div id="chart-container">
      <h3>Bar Chart</h3>
      <svg className="svg-canvas" width="800px" height="400px"></svg>
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Option 2

Update the state and use a second effect to update d3

```
const Barchart = ({ chartData }) => {
  let newArray = [];
  let len = chartData.length;

  const [XArray, setXArray] = useState([chartData]);
  const [Yarray, setYArray] = useState(chartData[len - 1].anArray); //so the initial state here should be an empty array
  // const d3Container = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let len = chartData.length;
    console.log(chartData.length);
    newArray = chartData[len - 1].anArray;
    setYArray(newArray);
  }, [chartData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Yarray.length) {
      const height = 70; //height of the actual chart, different than the svg element
      const width = 26.5 * Yarray.length; //width of the actual chart, different than the svg element

      const svg = d3.select(".svg-canvas");
      svg.selectAll("*").remove();

      var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 7]).range([0, width]);
      var y = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(Yarray)])
        .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(8);
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);

      //locate the chart in the middle of the svg frame: 800/2 - width/2
      var chartGroup = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (400 - width / 2) + ",300)");

      chartGroup
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(Yarray)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", (d, i) => d * 3)
        .attr("width", "15")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("x", (d, i) => 26.5 * i)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => height - d * 3);

      chartGroup
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(Yarray)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .attr("x", (d, i) => 26.5 * i)
        .attr("y", (d, i) => height - 5 - d * 3 + 2)
        .text((d, i) => d);

      chartGroup
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis y")
        // .attr('transform','translate(500,76)')
        .call(yAxis);

      chartGroup
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    }
  }, [Yarray]);

  const newArrayFunc = (a) => {
    setYArray(a);
  };

  return (
    <div id="chart-container">
      <h3>Bar Chart</h3>
      <svg className="svg-canvas" width="800px" height="400px"></svg>
    </div>
  );
};
```